# Forced conversion when using gsub on R? not sure why this is happening

Tags: r, pattern-matching, gsub

just wondering if anybody can clarify the below. So

```
    > sample<-"10B"
    > "10" * 10000
```

#Character * numeric, doesn't work

```
    Error in "10" * 10000 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
    > "10" * "10000000"
```

#character * character, doesn't work

```
    Error in "10" * "10000000" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
    > gsub("B",1000000,sample)
```

#for some reason, when substitute character with numeric, comes out with numeric*numeric in character.

```
[1] "101e+06"
```

Can somebody please help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` coerces replacement value to character. From `?gsub` :

> replacement - a replacement for matched pattern in sub and gsub. Coerced to character if possible.

```
result <- gsub("B",1000000,sample)
result
#[1] "101000000"
```

So number `1000000` is changed to character while replacement and `class(result)` is character.